# Can I make a digital time capsule?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, algorithm

Say I wanted to make a super awesome time capsule of some digital information. How would I encrypt it so that no one would be able to open it until a specified date? (E.g. 100 years from now.) At which point, anyone should be able to open it. Assuming that we follow a similar technological trajectory, (and things like quantum computers do not exist,) is this possible?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/991 ​ ​

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/is-it-possible-to-make-time-locked-encrytion-algorithm might help you.

Comment: @RickyDemer has given a great link, although the two top answers are contradictory.

Comment: Given that there are already several questions like this on at crypto.stackexchange.com and these questions have good answers I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here.

Comment: Perfect -- thank you for the links. I guess I was just looking on the wrong forum! I think we can go ahead and close this question out, since it's really well covered over there.